# This database.sql not working correctly?

Tags: mysql, sql, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get this to work but I don't understand how SQL works outside of the basics. Can you find the error in this?

```
CREATE TABLE lil_urls (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  url text,
  date timestamp(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) TYPE=MyISAM;
```

I'm currently getting this error in PhPMyAdmin:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(14) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)' at line 4
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE lil_urls (
  id varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  url text,
  date timestamp NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;
```

`TYPE` is no longer used and you need to use as `ENGINE`
And no need to specify length for `timestamp`